# How can I loop through the elements of the multidimensional array and search for a match?

Tags: vhdl

How can I loop through the elements of the array (recarr1)?
My goal is that I want find a matching f1 value and then output the related f2 value. The array must be stored as ROM.

The problem comes out of a book and is not related to a real world application.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity recordtest is
port(
address: in integer range 0 to 15;
data_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture recorder of recordtest is

type t_rec1 is record                  -- Declare a record with two fields
   f1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   f2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
end record t_rec1;

type t_rec1_array is array (natural range 0 to 255) of t_rec1;

constant recarr1 : t_rec1_array := (
   1      => (f1 => x"0111", f2 => x"0111"),
   2      => (f1 => x"0011", f2 => x"0111"),
   others => (f1 => x"1111", f2 => x"0111"));

begin


end architecture;
```

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. You can't iterate over record members, so you can only iterate over the outermost dimension.

Comment: A multi-dimensional array has multiple index range declarations which isn't present in type t_rec1_array. There's a distinction between a record composite type which has named elements of arbitrary type and an array composite type whose elements share the same subtype.

Comment: The accepted answer's function is dependent on the ROM's content being unique (only one `recarr(i).f1 = f1`). You could replace the answer function with an equivalent if statement returning `f2` for some value of `f1` demonstrating that the accepted answer represents a priority encoder selecting the first match depending on the direction and bounds of `recarr1'range`. In a Contents Associative Memory you'd otherwise need a mechanism for dealing with multiple matches (an output per `i` value denoting a match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to loop through the array and search for the first match:

```
function get_f2 (f1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
  variable result : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
  result := (others => 'X');

  for i in recarr1'range loop
    if (recarr1(i).f1 = f1) then
      result := recarr1(i).f2;
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;

  return result;
end function get_f2;
```

Note that this is a "brute-force" approach. It will run in a single cycle. But if your array/ROM is too large, then this won't work of course. In that case you'll need a design which tries one/a few entries each cycle and signals when it's finished the search.

The `recarr1` array can be stored in ROM, since it's read-only. It's not influenced in any way by this function.

I guess there's something missing from your example though, since it's not clear to me where you're getting the `f1` input to this function.